# R subset() x must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r, subset

What is wrong with this code snippet? Why I get this error:

> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list
>       Have you called 'sort' on a list?"

```
survey <- surveyFromCSV
survey <- subset(survey, survey$X6 != "german")
survey <- factor(survey)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

survey is a data.frame so what do you expect `factor(survey)` to do?

If you want to convert everything to factors then you may do:

```
survey <- data.frame(lapply(survey,as.factor))
```